# ¿Por que no me muestra la grafica de la data que inserto en un Chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

Guiándome de la [documentación](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) la data es un ejemplo como el de ellos, sin embargo no me muestra la data.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 15,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 25,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 35,
        y: 25
    }],
    options: {
        scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
        },
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0, // disables bezier curves
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 180px; width: 633px;" height="180" width="633"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La `data` no es como la vi en la documentacion, no se si es confusión mía o de ellos, en fin, la `data` es como este ejemplo que expongo.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
     {
       label: '# of Votes',
       data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
       borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132,1)'
     }
  ]
  },
    options: {
        scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    maxRotation: 0 // angle in degrees
                  }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    maxRotation: 0 // angle in degrees
                  }
                }]
        },
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0, // disables bezier curves
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 180px; width: 633px;" height="180" width="633"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que sucede es que

```
data: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 15,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 25,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 35,
        y: 25
    }],
```

Es como se definen intervalos o puntos, [Point[]](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) 
y deben ser definidos en cada datasets

```
data:{
 datasets:{
  data: //here 
 }
}
```

Tambien el tipo de grafica debe ser `type: 'scatter'`
Aqui te dejo un ejemplo sacado de la [documentacion](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset Ejemplo',
            data: [{
                x: -10,
                y: 0,
            }, {
                x: 0,
                y: 10
            }, {
                x: 10,
                y: 5
            }]
        }]
    },
    options: {
       scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 180px; width: 633px;" height="180" width="633"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es mejor entre las 2? o ¿En cuales casos se deberían usar los distintos modos que hay? Solo pregunto para dejar en claro la respuesta :D